# MY Site creation feature to be disabled

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, mysite

I have a SharePoint 2013 on premise environment consisting of site collections and Mysites. Now customer want that users should not be able to create My sites in the environment and so I went and uncheck the permission for creating personal sites from Central Admin.

But even after that if any new user once click on About Me on any page in the site, their Mysite gets created after 15-20 mins. Is there any features which needs to be disabled? What is the best approach to meet customer requirement?

PS: Customer also require the removal of previous MySite created in the environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to turn off the self-service site Creation options for my sites.

> Self-Service Site Creation allows users to create and manage their own
>   top-level websites automatically. When you turn on Self-Service Site
>   Creation for a web application, users can create their own top-level
>   websites under a specific path (by default, the /sites path).
>   Self-Service Site Creation can be configured to create sites, instead
>   of site collections, automatically. When turned on, this capability
>   advertises itself with a new site link added to the Sites page of
>   users' personal sites.

You can turn it off using the following steps:

- Login onto central admin > Application management > Manage Web applications
- Click on the MySite Web Application and from the ribbon, click on Self-Service Site Creation.
- On this page click **Off** and hit **Ok**.

I think you need to manually delete the old mysites.

Comment: But self service site creation allows user to create site collection by their own. turning it off wont let them create site collection as well.. cant do that!!

Comment: Turning off self-service site create on the my site web application, will only prevent people from creating site collections on the my site web application.  They will still be able to create sites on other web applications.